# C++ Buddy System Representation Using Array of Integers

Tags: c++

For a project from class, we are supposed to emulate memory management by using an array of integers and either singly/doubly linked lists or the buddy system. I chose to try and create a buddy system, but I'm afraid I lack allot of knowledge on how they are implemented, and I haven't been able to find any good resources on a basic step-by-step on the theory and application. The Wiki page made little sense.

This is how I figured I would calculate the size needed for each buddy. If the user asked for 1000 bytes, it would find the next highest 2^X number of bytes.

```
    double y = 2;
    for (double x = 1, y = 2; y <= bytes; x++)
        y = pow(2, x);
```

After that, though, I'm lost.

So I have a few questions:

1. Am I biting off more than I can chew with the buddy system as my first attempt at basic memory management?
2. Are there any good step-by-step resources on the buddy-system and C++?

Comment: I doubt that there are any specific resources on how to implement it. The algorithm isn't really useful in the real world. In general, you need to functions: one that requests memory and one that frees memory. Then you need some static area that is your memory and the above functions will work on it. The wiki article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation also seems rather comprehensive. Also, if you are supposed to use an array of integers, I don't see why you are talking about bytes.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, the tests we are supposed to run are supposed to allow both x bytes-worth of integers and a certain number of them to be requested. And it isn't that the wiki page wasn't comprehensive, I'm just having trouble making sense of it on my own.